# Rails Concerns And Conditional Features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `Addressable` Concern that is working well, but in some of my models, I have a need for mailing address and country, in others, I just want a simple address, and make an assumption about the country.

Is there a good way to do this? `include` doesn't have a way to pass variables. Maybe it could look at a const on the class.

Maybe there's a way to have a `SimpleAddressable` concern that would have the basic fields, and have another Addressable concern could somehow inherit? I haven't seen concern inheritance as an option though.

**UPDATE**

I was previously going to look at `self.columns`, but that was giving me weird errors in my test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can inherit in concerns, according to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html. So, I ended up pulling out `SimpleAddressable` from `Addressable`.

```
module SimpleAddressable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        validates :address, length: { maximum: 200 }, allow_nil: true
        validates :city, length: { maximum: 50 }, allow_nil: true
        validates :region, length: { maximum: 50 }, allow_nil: true
        validates :postal_code, length: { maximum: 20 }, allow_nil: true
    end
end

module Addressable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include SimpleAddressable

    included do
        validates :mailing_address, length: { maximum: 200 }, allow_nil: true
        validates :mailing_city, length: { maximum: 50 }, allow_nil: true
        validates :mailing_region, length: { maximum: 50 }, allow_nil: true
        validates :mailing_postal_code, length: { maximum: 20 }, allow_nil: true
        belongs_to :country, optional: true
    end
end
```